# UndefVarError: histogram not defined in Julia

Tags: julia, histogram

I am trying to draw histogram as following :

```
using Plots; using PyPlot
pyplot() # Plots.PyPlotBackend()
x = 0:100;
result = rand(x,2000);
histogram(result)
```

However, it returns *UndefVarError* :

```
UndefVarError: histogram not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[156]:5
 [2] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1116
```

I followed [Plotting a histogram in Julia](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/plotting-a-histogram-in-julia/20361/13) but returns the error.

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to re-produce this error in Julia 1.6.3. When I run:

```
julia> using Plots; using PyPlot

julia> pyplot() # Plots.PyPlotBackend()
Plots.PyPlotBackend()

julia> x = 0:100;

julia> result = rand(x,2000);

julia> histogram(result)
```

I get:

[image: Histogram image]

Without any errors. This also works without running `using PyPlot` for me.

Comment: Works for me as well (I use 1.6.*). I use histogram all the time.